# AWS AutoScaling error Malformed input-Only one of EC2_CERT and EC2_PRIVATE_KEY is configured Usage:

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Iam new to AWS and i wanted  to test some services(Ec2,LoadBalancing,AutoScaling), I have done that through console successfully so far as i have now a loadbalancer that distributes traffic to  two working instances.
Now as i follow the Autoscaling documentation i first need to create a launch-config through CLI. The problem is when i do this i get this error

```
as-create-launch-config:  Malformed input-Only one of EC2_CERT and EC2_PRIVATE_KEY is configured
Usage:
as-create-launch-config
    LaunchConfigurationName  --image-id  value  --instance-type  value
   [--block-device-mapping  "key1=value1,key2=value2..." ] [--ebs-optimized 
   ] [--iam-instance-profile  value ]
   [--monitoring-enabled/monitoring-disabled  ] [--kernel  value ] [--key 
   value ] [--ramdisk  value ] [--group  value[,value...] ] [--spot-price 
   value ] [--user-data  value ]  [General Options]
For more information and a full list of options, run "as-create-launch-config --help"
```

i have tried all the options of as-create-launch-config command and it keeps throwing the same error even if i just typed as-create-launch-config with no parameters.I even tried to skip that and run as-create-auto-scaling-group throws same error

i searched for the error and someone mentioned that this error is  because the credential file path is not set correctly :

http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=planetatecnologia.com%2Ftutorial-do-auto-scaling-com-exemplos-pratico&act=url

but iam pretty sure that all my paths are correct(i double checked all of them)

Iam using a linux machine and i exported AWS_AUTOSCALING_HOME,EC2_HOME,EC2_PRIVATE_KEY,AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE variables beside setting PATH and iam accesing AWS through credential file only not with certificate.

Is there something wrong in my configuration or did i forgot to do anything?

What iam doing wrong???

Comment: If you're using a credentials file (access key id and secret access key) you don't need to specify a private key.

Comment: @FrederickCheung you were right it worked when i removed the private file specification. thnx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe that the problem was that i was specifying both the credential file and the private key(stupid me), it worked just fine when i removed the private file specification i can't believe i wasted half day on that.

I hope the solution can help any one stuck with this error